# Select Causing CSS Grid Issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to set up a Flex/CSS Grid solution for my forms but at least one of the control types I am using, I have narrowed it down to the select, is causing all of the controls within their CSS Grid to overflow the bounds of the flex display area.

Some other information:

Platform: Wordpress

Theme: Jupiter

Tabs Plugin: WP Tabs Responsive horizontal vertical and accordion Tabs

Here is the code and how it is rendering:

```css
.GridDiv {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  grid-gap:5px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<label id="errMsg" style="color: red; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"></label><br />
<label for="NewUsrFrm">New User Form:</label>
<form id="NewUsrFrm" method="post" action="/grant/php/addUser.php">
  <fieldset>
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div style="width: 280px;">
        <div style="float: left;">
          <legend>User Information</legend>
          <div class="GridDiv">
            <label for="UsrFName">First Name:</label> <input type="text" name="UsrFName" width="120" />

            <label for="UsrLName">Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="UsrLName" width="120" />

            <label for="UsrAge">Age:</label> <input type="number" min="1" name="UsrAge" value="1" width="120" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div style="width: 280px;">
        <div style="float: left;">
          <legend>Login Information</legend>

          <div class="GridDiv">
            <label for="UsrName">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="UsrName" width="120" />

            <label for="UsrPass">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="UsrPass" width="120" />

            <label for="UsrGrp">Group:</label> <input type="number" name="UsrGrp" width="120" />

            <label for="UsrType">Type:</label>
            <select name="UsrType" width="100">
              <option value="0">Student</option>
              <option value="1">Parent</option>
              <option value="2">Administrator</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <button type="submit" id="frmBtnSub">Create User</button>
</form>
```

[image: css display issue]

Note: You will probably need a WordPress site and you will need to install the plugin mentioned above to test the code I have posted.

---

Update:

I have managed to hack around it using the inspector to see what the first fieldset inputs were being rendered with on their width.

When I apply that to the controls in the second fieldset they display correctly for the other controls; the select continues to be petulant.  So I guess the question now is why one fieldset's controls are being propertly rendered but if a select is in the second set, they do not.

Even if I use !important, the select is not using the width css attribute I am trying to assign to it.  What happens when you have two !important css attributes but one has a higher specificity?

Comment: looks like we're missing the CSS that makes your image look that way.

Comment: @sweaver2112 It is not intended to as I am using Wordpress and the tab structure is from a plugin which I have mentioned in the OP in case someone else using WP wants to check.

Comment: i think you're the "OP" actually (original poster is what that stands for)

Comment: @sweaver2112 OP can also stand for Original Post, which I assume is the meaning Geowil was using